# polar transformation

Tags: analysis

i need some help.
i have given 
$F(t)=\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{\,-tx^2}cos(x^2)\,dx$ and $G(t)=\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{\,-tx^2}sin(x^2)\,dx$ with t>0

I have to show with polar transformation that
$F^2(t)-G^2(t) = \frac{\pi \cdot t}{4(1+t^2)}$ and  $2F(t)G(t) = \frac{\pi}{4(1+t^2)}$

the hint was to start with $(F(t)+i\,G(t))^2$

$(F(t)+i\,G(t))^2 = \int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2(t-i)\
}\,dx= \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^\infty r e^{-r^2(t-i)\
}\,dr\,d\varphi$

so i did so far but i don't get the right solution.
can someone give me the right solution please ?

Comment: See [Fresnel Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Comment: @FelixMarin See how I've implemented your suggestion below.

Comment: @CyeWaldman I just read it. Quite nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F^2-G^2$ and $2FG$ are respectively the real and imaginary part of $(F+iG)^2$. Since

$$ F+iG = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left((i-t) x^2\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left((i-t)x^2\right)\,dx\tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ (F+iG)^2 = \frac{1}{4}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left((i-t)(x^2+y^2)\right)\,dx\,dy =\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\rho e^{(i-t)\rho^2}\,d\rho\tag{2}$$
and:
$$ (F+iG)^2 = \frac{\pi}{4(t-i)} = \frac{\pi(t+i)}{4(t^2+1)}\tag{3}$$
The claim easily follows.

Answer (score 3):

Picking up on the comment of @FelixMarin above, I demonstrate how to evaluate the integral directly in terms of the error function. Given

$$F(t)=\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{\,-tx^2}cos(x^2)\,dx \quad\text{ and }\quad G(t)=\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{\,-tx^2}sin(x^2)\,dx$$

we can write

$$F(t)+iG(t)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{x^2(i-t)}dx$$

Now, let $i\frac{\pi}{2}u^2=(i-t)x^2$, and $dx=\sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{2(i-t)}}du$, then

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}e^{x^2(i-t)}dx
&=\sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{2(i-t)}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}u^2}du\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{2(i-t)}}\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\text{erf}\left( \frac{1-i}{2}\sqrt{\pi}u\right)\big|_{u=\infty}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{2(i-t)}}\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right),\quad [\text{erf}(\infty)=1]\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4(t-i)}}
\end{align}
$$
The polar integral is quite straightforward, so we can readily show that

$$[F(t)+i\,G(t)]^2 = \left[\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2(t-i)\
}\,dx\right]^2=\frac{1}{4} \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^\infty r e^{-r^2(t-i)\
}\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{\pi}{4(t-i)}$$

in agreement with the solution of Jack D'Aurizio.

Comment: +1. Fresnel, in this case, is a straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

note if you are not familiar with solving complex integrals: to solve the integral in $(2)$ just compute it like you would solve an integral in $\mathbb{R}$. You can apply the fundamental theorem of analysis for the inner integral. the resulting does not depend on $φ$, so you can simply multiply the result by $2\pi$ to solve the outer integral.

Comment: thank you for the hint but im familiar with complex integrals :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this in the role of a devil's advocate. My problem is that it is obvious that

$$z=e^{-x^2(t-i)}=re^{i\theta}$$

is akin to a logarithmic spiral. Just plot it for $t<<1$ (e.g., $t=.05$) to see it clearly.

So my point is, how do you get to $r\to\infty$ if $\theta\to 2\pi$?

Comment: you have this one $\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R^2}}e^{-(x^2+y^2)(t-i)}dx\,dy $
and you want to do the polar transformation and you want to integrate over $\mathbb{R^2}$ so you have to use $\varphi \in [0,2\pi]$ to integrate over a circle and to reach all of $\mathbb{R^2}$ you must take $r\in[0,\infty]$.

Comment: @Otto.t In your original post, did you mean that $$(F(t)+i\,G(t))^2 = \int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2(t-i)\
}\,dx=\frac{1}{4} \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^\infty r e^{-r^2(t-i)\
}\,dr\,d\varphi?$$ Because that is what JackD'Aurizio has shown. Notice the factor of 1/4 in the polar integral.